# Diferrence between running a function and call a function that return a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
    // parameter is the user state of the auth
    // onAuthStateChanged: method from auth library
    const unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
    })
    // returned function will be called on component unmount
    return () => unsubscribeFromAuth();
  }, []);
```

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between return () => unsubscribeFromAuth();
with returning unsubscribeFromAuth() directly?
Thanks

Comment: If you `return unsubscribeFromAuth()` you _immediately_ unsubscribe and return the (`undefined`) return value. If you return a function, whatever is _calling_ the outer function (in this case React's internal machinery) decides when that happens.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @jonrsharpe. Also: would `return unsubscribeFromAuth` not accomplish the same?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function which has return like this

```
return () => unsubscribeFromAuth();
```

It is going to return a function using which you can call unsubscribeFromAuth directly

But if you call a function with this return

```
return unsubscribeFromAuth()
```

It returns the actual value by calling that function

Hope you understood

Answer (score 1):

```
                        unsubscribeFromAuth():
```

you are simply calling the function and it will run immedietly

```
                   return () => unsubscribeFromAuth():
```

but this time you are not calling that function, rather give it to the useEffect hook as a [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)(according to React). and when the corresponding component unmount the cleanup function will then run to unsubscribe. without cleanup the component might not works after rerender as expected